# Is there any work around to have categories and/or sub categories for blog posts in Shopify?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am trying to grasp how blog works in Shopify.

First of all I could not find a solution for having categories or sub categories for blog posts.

All I can do is create multiple blogs and consider them as categories. If I go with this option I have trouble displaying blog titles on home page along with each post so visitors can understand what kind of post it is. I have tried this with tag but in that case I have to sacrifice real usage of tags because a post used to have more than one tag in it. My code looks like:

```
<section class="trend-sec">
   <div class="container">
      <h2 class="sec-title">Trending</h2>
      <div class="row">
        {% for article in blogs.trending.articles limit:4 %}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">


          <div class="img-wraper">


            <a href="{{ article.url }}">


              <div class="img-cap-lab">

                <h4>{{ article.tags }}</h4>

              </div>

              {% if article.image %}
                    {% assign image_alt = article.title | escape %}
                    {{ article | img_url: 'medium' | img_tag: image_alt, 'article__image' | link_to: article.url }}

                  {% else %}
                    </div>
                  {% endif %}

              <div class="img-desc">

                    <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>
                    <h5>by {{ article.author }}, {{ article.published_at | date: "%b %d %Y" }}</h5>

              </div>

            </a>

          </div> 
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```